# Sidekiq: Wrong number of arguments (4 for 3) error in perform_async

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using Rails(4.1.0) and Sidekiq(3.2.1) and acts_as_tenantInstalling (0.3.5)

Here is my worker.

```
class NotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(current_account_id, notification_method_name, resource_id)
    current_account = Account.find(current_account_id)

    # Prcocess only if current account is not nil
    if current_account.present?
        ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(current_account) do
          # Current tenant is set for all code in this block
            notification_service = NotificationService.new
            notification_service.method(notification_method_name).call(resource_id)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

I am calling perform_async form assignments_controller.

```
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        current_account_id = current_tenant.id
        resource_id = @assignment.id
        NotificationWorker.perform_async(current_account_id, "assignment_notification", resource_id)
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am getting "wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)" from the line having sidekiq call in the controller. I have gone through documentation as well as other questions but can't figure out what i am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Update:

The error was coming because of requiring sidekiq support in acts_as_tenant gem.

```
ActsAsTenant.configure do |config|
  #ActsAsTenant supports Sidekiq. A background processing library.
  require 'acts_as_tenant/sidekiq'

  # When set to true will raise an ActsAsTenant::NoTenant error, whenever 
  # a query is made without a tenant set.   
  config.require_tenant = false # true

end
```

Comment: Have you tried just restarting your sidekiq daemon?

Comment: Yes, several times. ctrl + C and then restarting using $ bundle exec sidekiq . Trying to fix it since hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
notification_method_name = "assignment_notification"

NotificationWorker.perform_async(current_account_id, notification_method_name, resource_id)
```

Or maybe you can try use symbols, like [here](https://github.com/aprescott/sidekiq-symbols).